# AWS API Gateway: How to combine multiple Method Request params into a single Integration Request param

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I'd like to use API Gateway as a proxy to S3. The bucket is keyed by a composite key made up of two parts like this: [userId]-[documentId].

UserId comes to API Gateway as a path parameter, documentId comes in as a request parameter, for example: `[gateway-url]/user1?documentId=doc1`

How can I combine the two so that the s3 lookup URL has the following format: `https://[bucket-url]/user1-doc1`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Setup your Method Request to accept the path param {userid} and query param {docid}.
2. Setup your Integration Request to accept both `method.request.querystring.docid` and `method.request.path.userid` as URL path params.
3. Finally, setup your integration endpoint URL as https://your-url/{userid}-{docid}.

A swagger snippet for this is as follows-

```
"paths": {
"/concat-params/{userid}": {
  "get": {
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "userid",
        "in": "path",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "docid",
        "in": "query",
        "required": false,
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "responses": {...},
    "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
      "responses": {...},
      "requestParameters": {
        "integration.request.path.userid":"method.request.path.userid",
    "integration.request.path.docid":"method.request.querystring.docid"
      },
      "uri": "https:.../{userid}-{docid}",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps,
Ritisha.