# Mapping multiple values for x-amazon-apigateway-integration.requestParameters for a single key?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create a new API on Amazon API gateway but for my use-case I want to concatenate 2 values for a single key in request parameters. How can we specify multiple values for a single key in `integration.requestParameters`?

This is what I'm trying to achieve but the syntax is not correct and it's giving me error:

[image: screen]

For one to one mapping we use something like this

```
integration.request.querystring.start: "method.request.querystring.oauth_code"
```

[Documentation link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration-requestParameters.html)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: This is what I have tried so far:
`integration.request.querystring.Message.foo: method.request.path.foo`
`integration.request.querystring.Message.bar: method.request.querystring.bar`

But it did not work: `Start of list found where not expected`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by following instructions in this [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39969023/13370526).

Basically you need to add multiple parameters in the endpoint URL itself in the integration request, make sure that you are accepting those parameters as URL Path Parameters in the Integration Request.